# Plot functions from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: calculus, geometry, graphing-functions

Suppose there is a function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $f(x,y)=(x',y')$.

(For example: $f(x,y)=(x+y,y+2)$).

Can we draw a graph of this function in Cartesian coordinates? Thank you.

Comment: You would need to be able to represent a 4-dimensional object (the graph, which consists of pairs of the form $\bigl( (a,b), (c,d)\Bigr)$ with $(c,d)=f(a,b)$); we have a hard enough time doing this with function $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, which only require us to represent a 3-dimensional object in two dimensions. So... not really.

Comment: Yes, provided that you have a piece of four-dimensional graph paper.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't understand how this function represent 4 dimensional object. I thought f maps a point on x-y coordinate to a points in another x-y coordinate, so there are two coordinates.

Comment: The function does not “represent a four dimensional object”. The **graph** would have to be a four-dimensional object. Look: a one-variable function with real values maps the 1-dimensional real line to the 1-dimensional real line, but the graph is a 2 (1+1) dimensional object. A map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ maps the 2-dimensional plane to the 1-dimensional line, and so its graph is a 3 (2+1) dimensional object. A function mapping the plane to the plane has a graph which is a 2+2=4-dimensional object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain and range of this function constitute four dimensions.  Typically, you would plot a subset of the domain and its image on two separate 2D graphs.  This is also how you would study the domain and range of complex functions.

Comment: So, the coordinates of domain and coordinates of range are different?

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate more on D.B.'s answer, you can draw the image of various straight lines (for example) to get some sense on what your map is happening.
Here I drew the image of a few lines of the form $x=c$ (blue) and $y=c$ (red) in the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$. I hope you see the effect:
[image: Image of grid lines under OP's transformation]

The lines with asterisks are the images of $x=0$ and $y=0$. Here we see that the whole square moved upwards by 2 units and underwent a shear transformation with its upper half stretching linearly to the right (and its bottom -- to the left).

For more complex mappings these straight lines may not give a very descriptive view of what's going on. Anyway, if you want to experiment, here's the octave code I used to generate this picture:

```
# The transformation to plot
x_hat = @(x, y) x + y;
y_hat = @(x, y) y + 2;

x_breaks = y_breaks = -1 : 0.125 : 1;

# At which points each horizontal (vertical) line will be mapped and drawn.
# A discretized parameter of the curves.
horizontal_lines = -1 : 0.1 : 1;
vertical_lines = -1 : 0.1 : 1;

figure 1; clf; hold on;

# Image of vertical lines at fixed longtitudes
for c = x_breaks
  xx = arrayfun(@(y) x_hat(c, y), vertical_lines);
  yy = arrayfun(@(y) y_hat(c, y), vertical_lines);
  v = plot(xx, yy, ifelse(c, 'b', '-*b')); 
end

# Image of horizontal lines at fixed latitudes
for c = y_breaks
  xx = arrayfun(@(x) x_hat(x, c), horizontal_lines);
  yy = arrayfun(@(x) y_hat(x, c), horizontal_lines);
  h = plot(xx, yy, ifelse(c, 'r', '-*r')); 
end

legend([v, h], "f(x=c, y)","f(x, y=c)", "location", "southoutside")
```

You'd get a better feeling probably if you try some more curvy maps on your own, for exmpale with the above code for the map $(x,y)\mapsto(\frac{x}{3 - y},y + 0.5\cos(x))$ I get the following picture:

[image: Image of a line grid under a non-linear transformation]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function f : R²→R² is sufficiently continuous, you can visualize it like this: Let S be an at least 2 dimensional vector space of colors (and/or textures). Let V: R²→S be continuous and (at least locally) 1-to-1. Then V should be a sufficiently nice assignment of colors/textures to the plane to make the color/texture assignment (x,y) →V(f(x,y)) a good visualization of f.